# Hardware problem? iphone12 consumes more time on VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame and AVAssetWriter than iphoneXs

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avassetwriter, video-toolbox

**This question is similar with**
[https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127613]

In my demo, the average execution time of **VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame** **in iphone12 is 10ms** while **iphoneXs only costs 6ms.** If I decrease the frequency of calling that function, the execution time also decreases but the total time(delay+execution time) stays same about 11ms on iphone12 and 7ms on iphoneXs.
I try various configuration of VTCompressionSession, but the result **(iphone12 > iphoneXs)** never change！
Here is the configuration of VTCompressionSession

```
bool VideoToolboxEncoder::InitCompressionSession() {
  CFMutableDictionaryRef sourceImageBufferAttributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL, NULL);
  CFDictionarySetValue(sourceImageBufferAttributes, kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey, kCFBooleanTrue);
  CFDictionaryRef io_surface_value = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  CFDictionarySetValue(sourceImageBufferAttributes, kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey, io_surface_value);
  OSType target_pixelformat = kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar;
  dict_set_i32(sourceImageBufferAttributes,
                 kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, target_pixelformat);
  dict_set_i32(sourceImageBufferAttributes,
                 kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey, 16);
  CFDictionarySetValue(sourceImageBufferAttributes, kCVPixelBufferWidthKey, CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &codec_settings.width));
  CFDictionarySetValue(sourceImageBufferAttributes, kCVPixelBufferHeightKey, CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &codec_settings.height));
  OSStatus status = VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL,
                                      codec_settings.width,
                                      codec_settings.height,
                                      kCMVideoCodecType_HEVC,
                                      NULL,
                                      sourceImageBufferAttributes,
                                      NULL,
                                      encodeComplete,
                                      this,
                                      &compression_session_);
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime, kCFBooleanTrue);
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowFrameReordering, kCFBooleanFalse);
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ExpectedFrameRate, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@(29.97));
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval,
                                (__bridge CFTypeRef)@(codec_settings.gop_size));
  CFStringRef profileRef;
  profileRef = kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel;
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel, profileRef);
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowOpenGOP, kCFBooleanFalse);
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@(codec_settings.bitrate));
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(compression_session_, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_DataRateLimits, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@[@20000000, @2]);
  VTCompressionSessionPrepareToEncodeFrames(compression_session_);
  return 0;
}
```

I also tryed to export video with **AVAssetWriter** and I got the same result.

**It's unexpected that videotoolbox performance decreases on  newer iphones.**
**I want to figure out this problem is due to my incorrect configuration or hardware of iphone.**
Has anyone encountered the same problem？If someone could help with this issue would be really grateful!